# Why are "identity" column values incorrect when I attach a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Someone sent me a database (via means of an `.mdf` and `.ldf` file) which I attached on a server (with no errors, warnings, etc) and though I don't have proof (since I don't have access to the server the DB came from), it appears the primary key (identity) values are different from what they were originally. Also, they appear to be "reset" - all primary key values are starting at 1, whereas based on foreign key references it is clear that is incorrect (for example, a table with only 1 row has a primary key value of 1, but a table that references it references a value of 7).

Though I don't really care, I am curious as to why this is happening (if there is an explanation)?

What I really need is to figure out if there is a way to attach the database and retain the proper values?

**Edit:**
As far as I can tell, the foreign key references are set up properly.

Here are some screenshots:
[image: foreign key relationship]
[image: foreign key relationship columns]
[image: WTF!?]

Comment: I have never attached a file where the identity values changed. I would suspect a db that was not correctly designed for data integrity. In the structure are there actual Foreign keys set up? Given what you described I suspect not.

Comment: @HLGEM Indeed there are foreign key relationships set up (correctly, as far as I can tell). Which is what makes the situation of having incorrect referential data so confusing. I added some screenshots to the question, check them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I can think of since there are FKs is that they had a bad design to start with and then someone realized they neede FKs but there was already bad data they didn't want delete and thus created the FKs WITH NOCHECK

Are all of the orphaned records early ID numbers?

Comment: Seems a reasonable possibility but very unlikely because: there is a table which has language options (with a PK identity column called `LanguageID`) which only has 1 row; that row's `LanguageID` is `1`. In *all* of the tables which reference it, the rows' `LanguageID`s are `7`.

Comment: Indeed the screen shot in the question has "No" selected for the "Check Existing Data" option.

Comment: @Martin Ah sorry, I missed that. Still doesn't really explain how the database went from "supposedly working" to having invalid data all over the place without suspecting foul play, but as the saying goes, the world may never know.

Answer (score 1):

Attaching a database never changes table content. The values you see are all coming from the application that created the database. [``select’’ Isn’t Broken](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips).

Comment: While I completely agree with you in concept, the application was working perfectly with this database on the other server. Which leads me to believe either something strange is happening when I attach the database, someone intentionally screwed up the database before sending it to me, or I have the wrong database - none of which seem likely.

Comment: If you are brave enough to venture into undocumented features then you can use `select ... from ::fn_dblog(null, null)` to analyze the log history of how those identity values got inserted, at least the log which is present in your DB. This would quickly show whether it happened before or after the attach. See http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Search-Engine-QA-6-Using-fn_dblog-to-tell-if-a-transaction-is-contained-in-a-backup.aspx for an example of using `fn_dblog`

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately the database is a "Simple" recovery model and isn't offering much in the way of transaction logs (only 43 rows). When I do `select * from ::fn_dblog(null, null)` there doesn't seem to be any rows which will be helpful (I'll keep looking though). I don't see any rows which are obviously changing the data, which still leaves me to wonder: if the data didn't change when the database was being attached, how the @#%(& can those FKs exist if the referential data values are incorrect?!